# Share Internet throught network interfaces

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, vmware

ok so i'm working in VMWare and have 2 virtual machines (Ubuntu and Windows 7). The Ubuntu machine has 2 network interfaces (eth0 & eht1), the eth0 interface is using NAT to connect to the internet through my real computer and the eth1 interface is using host-only to connect to the Windows machine. The windows machine only has one interface using host-only.

What i'm trying to do is share internet to the windows machine through the interfaces. I've tried the following commands but can't get it to work.

```
sudo iptables --flush
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your ubuntu instance would need to be forwarding (check: `sysctl -a | grep forward`) and have appropriate routes configured (`ip route`)

Comment: Please avoid posting resolving advice as comments; that is what "answers" are for. @user4556274

Answer (score 0):

You must enable IP forwarding in your Linux guest.
In /etc/sysctl.conf put this:
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
Then issue this command:

## sysctl -w

It should echo back the same line you put in the file.
Check if it was properly enabled:

## sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward

Should output 1 if enabled and 0 if disabled.
If required restart the networking service for changes to take effect.

Comment: `sysctl -w` produces the following output: `sysctl: no variables specified
Try sysctl --help for more information.`

Comment: Ok so I ran another command to see if it was enabled and it is enabled. But i'm still getting `Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage` in my Windows machine. :/

Comment: Can you ping between the two VMs?

Comment: Yeah. I'm able to ping between the two VMs

Comment: try with sysctl -p and read it with sysctl -a

Comment: You can also monitor if the packets are being forwarded or being blocked in the Linux VM, try this before opening a webpage in Internet Explorer: # iptables -vL and note the amount of packets in the FORWARD chain, then try to access the webpage and issue the same command again and compare the number of packets, if its the same then is not leaving the Linux VM, if it increases then your routing is enabled and working but your packets are not being routed back to your Windows VM, in that case check your NAT settings